# Переменная со скобками в BASCOM. Что это?

Tags: visual-basic, микроконтроллеры

Пытаюсь адаптировать под себя часы на микроконтроллере, найденные в интернете, в листинге с прошивкой столкнулся с вот такой переменной.

```
Dim Number(4) As Integer
```

Что дает это число в скобках и как правильно называется? По логике работы программы эта переменная не должна принимать значение больше 4. Но раньше нигде такого не видел.

Comment: Размер массива, если я не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

согласно информации из [учебника](http://decada.org.ru/project/lessons/bascom_avr/08/), так описывается массив.

а число в скобках — размерность массива.

---

собственно, на [сайте разработчика](http://www.mcselec.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=14&Itemid=103) указано, что

> BASCOM-AVR© is the original Windows BASIC COMPILER for the AVR family.

а в *ms/basic* [именно так](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wak0wfyt.aspx#BKMK_DeclaringAnArray) и задаётся размерность массивов.